# Splitting unicode string in separate words. Can you use 'space' to split?

Tags: php, unicode, split, full-text-search

I am developing a full text search backend with support for Unicode.

(Database PostgreSQL 9.5, PHP7, Ubuntu 17, Apache2).

The database is correctly indexing (using tsearch) the relevant text data. So far so good.

Now I need to search the data using user-supplied search words. My first idea is to split a searchstring using `explode(" ", $rawseachstring)` and then search for the individual words, generating a resultset with best matches.

However, Unicode seems to have a whole bunch of 'space-like' characters defined, see next article:

http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

After trying to understand that page (written by the Unicode guru Korpela), I wonder if splitting the string on ' ' is a bit naive.

Should one split on all possible 'space-like' characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [unicode property for spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property) `\p{Zs}`

```
$words = preg_split('/\p{Zs}/u', $rawseachstring);
```

Comment: thank you very much, just what I needed. It is hard to use unicode when one doesn't speak/write most languages it supports. This seems to match multiple varieties of 'space'.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect these kind of spaces then you can use preg_split to explode by a regex of multiple characters.

```
$words = preg_split('/regex/', $string);
```

However consider doing a query with `LIKE` keyword to get only the results that may match.

Comment: LIKE is not an option while using tsearch in postgres. But your suggection about splitting is sounds.  Toto gave a nice solution.